# Get a specific string

Tags: sql, sql-server, c#-4.0

It's my data and every `ThroughRouteSid` record has the same pattern.
six number and five comma. then I just want to get three and five
number into two record to template Table and get the same `Count()`
value to these two record.

For example: First record in the picture.

`ThroughRouteSid(3730,2428,2428,3935,3935,3938,) Count(32)`.

I want a result like this: 
`2428  32 3935  32` 
I get What number I want.become two record and both have same Count value into template table

[image: My data picture]

Comment: Don't store data as comma separated items, it will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: i had to deal with comma seperated values in a cell once, was so stressfull as they we foreign key IDs

Comment: Which DBMS are you using ? (MySQL, Oracle, Postgres , ... ?)

Comment: @kenfire says in the tags

Comment: Can I ask what kind of problem possible happen when I store data as comma separated item?

Answer (score 0):

you can use XML to get your result, please refer below sample code -

```
create table #t1( ThroughRouteSid varchar(500) , Cnt int)

insert into #t1
select '3730,2428,2428,3935,3935,3938,' , len('3730,2428,2428,3935,3935,3938,')
union all select '1111,2222,3333,4444,5555,6666,' , len('1111,2222,3333,4444,5555,6666,')

select   cast( '<xml><td>' + REPLACE( SUBSTRING(ThroughRouteSid ,1 , len(ThroughRouteSid)-1),',','</td><td>') + '</td></xml>' as xml) XmlData , Cnt 
into #t2  from #t1

select XmlData.value('(xml/td)[3]' ,'int' ), Cnt ,XmlData.value('(xml/td)[5]' ,'int' ), Cnt 
  from #t2
```

Answer (score 0):

First create the function referring [How to Split a string by delimited char in SQL Server](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/querying-microsoft-sql-server/2013/09/19/how-to-split-a-string-by-delimited-char-in-sql-server/). Then try Querying the following

```
select (SELECT CONVERT(varchar,splitdata) + ' '+ Convert(varchar, [Count])+' ' FROM (select splitdata, ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY (SELECT 100)) row_no 
from [dbo].[fnSplitString](ThroughRouteSid,',')
where splitdata != '') as temp where row_no in (2,5)
for xml path('')) as col1 from [yourtable]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2016 you can do something like this:

```
create table #temp (ThroughRouteSid varchar(1024),[Count] int)
insert into #temp values
('3730,2428,2428,3935,3935,3938,',32),
('730,428,428,335,935,938,',28)

select 
  spt.value,
  t.[Count]
from #temp t
cross apply (
    select value from STRING_SPLIT(t.ThroughRouteSid,',') where LEN(value) > 0
)spt
```